# how to remove dependencies Java

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi how I can remove dependecies in this code

```
public boolean removeJob(final JobEntity job) {

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    final boolean result = 
        updateByNamedQuery(JobQueries.REMOVE_JOB_X_BY_ID_KEY, job.getId()) > 0;
    if (result) {
        updateByNamedQuery(JobQueries.REMOVE_JOB_BY_ID_KEY, job.getId());
    }
    return result;
}
```

and Hibernate:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "JobEntity." + JobQueries.REMOVE_JOB_X_BY_ID_KEY, query
               JobQueries.REMOVE_JOB_TRIGGER_BY_ID)
```

Comment: Which dependencies do you want to remove?

Comment: When this code is called the logs show "breached referential dependency". How can I fix this?